# Reading pid from ssh process grep output from different servers

Tags: bash, ssh

Read PID coming from a process grep pipe command of each server and kill it.
when i ran the following snippet - it brings up the same ID as the first host for the remaining servers. In other words it doesn't update new PIDs

```
for h in host1 host2 host3
do
  if [ $(hostname -s) = $h ]; then
    PID=$(echo "`ps -ef | grep x_user | grep x_project | grep JMX_SCRIPT.PID=webservice | grep '/bin/bash' | awk '{print $2;}'`")
  else
    PID=$(ssh $h "echo \"`ps -ef | grep x_user | grep x_project | grep JMX_SCRIPT.PID=webservice | grep '/bin/bash' | awk '{print $2;}'`\"")
  fi

  echo "Killing pid - $PID... on $h"
  sleep 5
done
```

output coming as:

```
Killing pid - 18334... on host_1
Killing pid - 18334... on host_2
Killing pid - 18334... on host_3
```

Experts - What am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you on a Linux system?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `ssh` command:

```
PID=$(ssh $h "echo \"`ps -ef | grep x_user | grep x_project | grep JMX_SCRIPT.PID=webservice | grep '/bin/bash' | awk '{print $2;}'`\"")
```

The `ps -ef ...` part is being run on your local host, rather than the remote one.  That's why you are getting the same PID each time.

You could resolve this by storing the command pipeline in a file or a string and feeding it to `ssh`.

Comment: Would you read the command from a file and provide it to `ssh` as a single string, or would you read the command in an array first and expand that array in the `ssh` command?

Comment: I am not sure if the string way would work.  I am saying this because Charles Duffy had given a similar solution to an ssh question like this where I had recommended heredoc.  I removed his answer - I suspected he tested his approach and it didn't work.

Comment: I made a small toy-like test and it worked (the single-string approach), but I cannot authoritatively say there are no gotchas and remote-side quoting issues.  The array-based solution I proposed is (to my limited knowledge) as bullet-proof as you are likely to get, and avoids having to put code in a file just to make it possible to side-step quoting issues.  I much prefer keeping all the code in the script.

Comment: I agree - I also prefer the string / array approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the quoting.  Quoting inside quotes is tricky, and the best way to do what you want to do is often to do away with quoting inside quotes entirely.

First, put your remote command in an array :

```
declare -a remote_command=()
remote_command+=(ps -ef '|' grep x_user '|' grep x_project '|')
remote_command+=(grep JMX_SCRIPT.PID=webservice '|' grep '/bin/bash')
remote_command+=('|' awk '{print $2;}')
```

Then, run it like this :

```
PID="$(ssh $h "${remote_command[@]}")"
```

The array expansion will do what you need, i.e. provide each argument individually but without performing expansion or word splitting.  Especially, the "pipe" symbols (`|`) are not going to be interpreted locally, but will be passed as arguments to the `ssh` command, and will be interpreted remotely as pipes.

By the way, one advantage with this technique is that since your command is programmatically built, you can easily have optional parts (i.e. arguments) included or not with, for instance, simple `if` blocks with `+=` statements, and still no problem with error-prone quoting.